# how do i make the user input a double?

Tags: java, class, object, input, double

can somebody correct me what i did wrong here? my goal was for the user to input a number on the parameter System.out.print("Available Amount Before Upgrade:" + df.format(availAmount1));
double upgradeAccessories= sc.nextDouble(); but i can't seem to see the issue

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#####");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    double availAmount;
    
    Car owner = new Car();
    
    owner.owner("Marcus Laurence", 2014);
    
    double availAmount1=owner.upgradeAccessories(availAmount);
    double remainAmount=owner.upgradeAccessories(availAmount);
    
    System.out.println("Owner:" + owner.name);
    System.out.println("Model:" + owner.model);
    System.out.print("Available Amount Before Upgrade:" + df.format(availAmount1));
    double upgradeAccessories= sc.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("Installed AC:" + owner.hasAC);
    System.out.println("Installed Leather Seats:" + owner.hasLeatherSeats);
    System.out.println("Installed Back Wipers:"+ owner.hasBackWipers);
    System.out.println("Installed Fog Lights:" + owner.hasFogLights);
    System.out.println("Amount Remaining After Upgrade:" + df.format(remainAmount));
}

public double upgradeAccessories(double availAmount) 
{          

        if(availAmount == 25000)
        {
            availAmount -= 21500;
            hasAC=true;
        }
        
        else if(availAmount == 40000) 
        {
            availAmount -= 21500;
            availAmount -= 14400;
            hasAC=true;
            hasLeatherSeats=true;
        }
        else if(availAmount == 50500) 
        {
            availAmount -=21500;
            availAmount -=14400;
            availAmount -=6250;
            availAmount -=3300;
            hasAC=true;
            hasLeatherSeats=true;
            hasBackWipers=true;
            hasFogLights=true;
        }
        return availAmount;
    }
```

Comment: What exactly is the issue? You mentioned the expected behavior, but did not mention anything about what actually happens when you run the program.

Comment: Mentioning such information helps other in quickly finding problems, rather than first trying running it on their own machines

Comment: it says to duplicate local variable of the availAmount but when i do that,it says the availAmount may not have been initialized even though i checked

Comment: Maybe you want to do this,
availAmount = sc.nextDouble();
instead of double upgradeAccessories= sc.nextDouble();

Comment: it keeps telling me to initiate a variable on the double availAmount; and do like double availAmount = 0; and it works but when i run it the parameter System.out.print("Available Amount Before Upgrade:" + df.format(availAmount)); has now a 0 where i want the user to input the number

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *how do i make the user input a double?*

You did this part fine - `scanner.nextDouble()` is all it takes. Here's a really simple standalone example, including output:

```
System.out.print("enter a double: " );
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
double d = sc.nextDouble();
System.out.println("d: " + d);

enter a double: 123.456
d: 123.456
```

So reading a double is not the issue. However, this line is suspicious:

```
double upgradeAccessories = sc.nextDouble();
```

Why? A few reasons..

- It defines a new variable "upgradeAccessories" which is not used anywhere else – so it's reading a value (from `sc.nextDouble()`) and then doing nothing with it. This is something that an IDE (such as IntelliJ or Eclipse) will help you see – it will draw attention to unused code, like declaring a value that is never used.
- The name of the variable – "upgradeAccessories" – is the same as the method name defined elsewhere in your code, namely:

  ```
  public double upgradeAccessories(double availAmount)
  ```

So to fix your code, it seems that you probably want to replace this:

```
double upgradeAccessories = sc.nextDouble();
```

with something like this:

```
double next = sc.nextDouble();
owner.upgradeAccessories(next);
```

---

Also, the way you're comparing doubles is dangerous. Generally, fractional numbers are never exactly equal. Instead, of doing comparisons like this:

```
if (availAmount == 25000) { ... }
```

It's better to do something like greater-than-or-equal:

```
if (availAmount >= 25000) { ... }
```

Or if you're using only whole-number values, use integer instead of double, and then direct `x == y` comparisons will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

In this segment of your code...

```
double availAmount;
    
Car owner = new Car();
    
owner.owner("Marcus Laurence", 2014);
    
double availAmount1=owner.upgradeAccessories(availAmount);
```

... you passed the "availAmount" in to a function as a parameter.  You haven't given that variable any value yet.  You just declared it.  If you assign a default value to it like 0.0, does it work?

Comment: double availAmount=0;
  double availAmount1=owner.upgradeAccessories(availAmount);
  double remainAmount=owner.upgradeAccessories(availAmount);

  
  System.out.println("Owner:" + owner.name);
  System.out.println("Model:" + owner.model);
  System.out.print("Available Amount Before Upgrade:" + df.format(availAmount1));
  availAmount = sc.nextDouble(); //i did something like this but when i run the code the 0 variable of the double availAmount=0; is in the way where i wanted the user to input the numbers